# Comprobar pago por Paypal

Tags: php, html, paypal

acabo de hacer un e-commerce para un cliente, y estoy implementando el codigo que suministra Paypal para realizar los pagos. Hasta ahora al momento de hacer click en el boton de paypal, este redirecciona al usuario a la pagina oficial de paypal para que pueda realizar el pago.

Mi pregunta es: ¿hay alguna forma de comprobar que el usuario realizo el pago? Ya que necesito imprimir un recibo o un comprobante justo al momento de que el pago haya sido realizado.

Gracias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PayPal utiliza un sistema IPN (Instant Payment Notification) que permite verificar que la transacción se ha realizado con éxito.
Tienes que definir una url de retorno en la configuración de paypal, allí es donde deberás alojar el script que se comunicará con los servicios de paypal para comprobar el estado de la transacción.

Con esto recogemos la respuesta de paypal y hacemos la comprobación haciendo uso de curl.

```
<?php

$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
$keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
if (count($keyval) == 2)
$myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}

$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if (function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
 $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
 }
 foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
 if ($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
 $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
} else {
$value = urlencode($value);
  }
 $req .= "&$key=$value";
}


$ch = curl_init('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));


if ( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {

 curl_close($ch);
  exit;
}
curl_close($ch);
```

La respuesta de PayPal está en la variable $res, así que comprobamos su valor:

```
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
  // Acción si PayPal verifica el pago
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
  // Acción si PayPal NO verifica el pago
}
```